# Small scale grid using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot, grids

I am trying to create a grid that only has a domain between -0.8 and 0 and a range between -0.8, 0,8, with the grid not showing any positive X values. Thus far I have this:

[image]

But when I try to shrink the domain down the whole grid shrinks. What is the best way to create this graph on a smaller scale but retain the same size?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!50, dashed] (-10,-5) grid (0,5);
\draw[<-,ultra thick] (-10,0)--(0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[<-,ultra thick] (0,5)--(0,-5) node[top]{$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, how would I proceed to draw points within this diagram?

Comment: Do you mean `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]`?

Comment: @Sigur that does not seem to do anything for me

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you want to change the arrows length, you have to change the end points. What do you mean by *smaller scale but retain the same size*? What is scale for you?

Comment: `step=5mm` as grid option could be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find `pgfplots` and its `axis` environment useful. `pgfplots` is a package for plotting data or functions, that is based on TikZ. It does take a bit more setup, and it isn't always better than plain TikZ (that depends on the specifics of the diagram), but perhaps this is a case where it can be of help.

I've added some comments before the different options I added to the `axis` environment, so hopefully should be somewhat clear what they do. Do ask if anything is unclear. Also, the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) is a good reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  % axis lines along center, not on outer edges
  axis lines=center,
  % make axis lines thick
  axis line style={thick},
  % move arrow tip of x-axis to start of line
  x axis line style={stealth-},
  % set the range of the axis
  xmin=-0.8, xmax=0,
  ymin=-0.8, ymax=0.8,
  % distance between the ticks, so distance between grid lines
  xtick distance=0.1,
  ytick distance=0.1,
  % remove ticklabels
  xticklabels={},
  yticklabels={},
  % set size of axis box
  width=8cm, height=8cm,
  scale only axis,
  % add grid, and change its style
  grid,
  grid style={help lines,color=gray!50, dashed},
  % add axis labels
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  % move xlabel right of axis end point (default is above left)
  xlabel style={right}
]

% plot points at the given list of coordinates
\addplot [only marks,mark=*] coordinates {(-0.5,0.5) (-0.2,0) (-0.4,-0.3)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```